# SSL for website Azure Service fabrics

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-service-fabric

How can we setup an SSL for azure service fabrics website domain, since the server is going to run on 10 nodes. When i buying the certificate it is asking for CSR file. Where can i generate the CSR file since website is running on 10 nodes. How can i generate the CSR file regarding azure service fabrics website

I know about azure key vault where we will upload the the certificate and install on the nodes, but before doing that how can we generate CSR and get the Certificate from the providers like Symantec/Geotrust/godaddy

Can any one guide me for process of generating the CSR regarding azure service fabrics since it going to run on 10 nodes?

Answer (score 0):

TLS certificates help create an encrypted channel between a browser and a web server while also authenticating the **identity** of the website that owns the cert. Your certificate is issued for one or more **domain names**, not nodes. You can use it on any number of nodes as long as the domain name the cert is issued for matches the site you are serving.

Most cert vendors provide tools to generate Certificate Signing Requests. An `OpenSSL` approach to the problem looks like this:

```bash
openssl req -new -sha256 -key domain.com.key -out domain.com.csr
```